# sending powershell script to Windows ec2 in user data

Tags: python, windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm following [these instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html) to bootstrap a Windows ec2 instance with a powershell script (call it "bootstrap.ps1"). However, it looks as if the script has never run when I log into the machine for the first time. I check C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Logs\Ec2ConfigLog, and I see this:

```
2014-03-11 00:08:02: Ec2HandleUserData: Start running user scripts
2014-03-11 00:08:02: Ec2HandleUserData: Could not find <script> and </script>
2014-03-11 00:08:02: Ec2HandleUserData: Could not find <powershell> and </powershell>
```

This is what my script looks like:

```
<powershell>
(multiple lines of powershell script here)
</powershell>
```

I'm base64-encoding the script in Python and sending it through [boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html):

```
import base64
# (create connection to aws region in boto called 'conn')
conn = ...
# run the instance and provide base64-encoded bootstrap powershell script in user_data
with open("bootstrap.ps1", "r") as fd:
  conn.run_instances(..., user_data=base64.encodestring(fd.read()))
```

I've made sure that:

1. The script I'm sending ("bootstrap.ps1") is using \r\n as line endings
2. The script available at `http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data` base64-decoded is the same as the raw "bootstrap.ps1" I've written (verified by downloading it, then running through `base64.decodestring` in Python)
3. There are no characters before or after `<powershell>` and `</powershell>` in "boostrap.ps1", respectively.

Clearly, I'm including `<powershell>` and `</powershell>` in user_data. These are encoded base-64, yet somehow they're not being found by ec2config? Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies in the encoding of `user_data`, which is already performed by `boto`. According to the [boto documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.instance), `user_data` should be "*[t]he Base64-encoded MIME user data to be made available to the instance(s) in this reservation,*" which I find to be *very* misleading, since the encoding need not and **should not** be done in the call to `run_instances`. The following Python works for me now:

```
# create connection...
conn = ...
# run instance
with open("bootstrap.ps1", "r") as fd:
  # don't encode user_data
  conn.run_instances(..., user_data=fd.read())
```